# Clone state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I've this code in my Reactjs-Redux application

```js
switch (action.type) {

    case SET_RISPOSTA:
    
                const newState = {...state}
                                newState.verifica.domande[action.indexDomanda].risposte[action.indexRisposta].valore = action.valore
                console.log(state.verifica.domande[0].risposte[0].valore)         console.log(newState.verifica.domande[0].risposte[0].valore)

            return newState

  default:

  return state

}
```

I expect that console shows

undefined (an undefined value)
1 (value of action.valore)

but console shows

1
1

Why did my state object is mutated even though I've used {...state}?

if i put

console.log(state.verifica.domande[0].risposte[0].valore)

before

const newState = {...state}

console shows

undefined
1

Comment: This is my first Stack Overflow question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `const newState = {...state}` creates a new object of `state` only. It does not create new object recursively. This means after doing `{...state}`, following will be different

```
state !== newState // true
```

but following will remain same

```
`newState.verifica` === `state.verifica` // true
```

Comment: Thancks!

I suspected that was the reason.

Have I to do the same thing i did for state for newState.verifica too? Is there a best way to do what I'm tryin to do?

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html here it suggests to "Copying All Levels of Nested Data" to mantain the old state immutated.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I commneted that in totally different context. Deleted the comment. Thanks for pointing that out.